# Is there a way to load nested properties from a property file in java?

Tags: java, configuration-files

The scenario what I am looking for is like.

```
//contents of props file

prop1
[prop1.1=val1
prop1.2=val2] 
prop2
[ prop2.1
         [prop2.1.1=val3
          prop2.1.2=val4
         ]
  prop2.2=val5
]
prop3=val6
```

//end

after loading this file, I should be able to access it like obj.get(prop1.prop1.1), obj.get(prop2.prop2.1.prop2.1.1), obj.get(prop3). these should return val1, val3 and val5 respectively.

I guess this is not possible with Properties class.

Comment: This looks well suited for XML or JSON.

Comment: This looks like some kind of bastardized JSON

Comment: I am looking for something similar to [configparser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) of python in java.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML